# Ubuntu for Samsung's Tab 3 8" Galaxy?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I Have a Samsung Tab 3 8" Galaxy, which uses an "Exynos Dual-core Processor.
Is there going to be a suitable version of Ubuntu for it?

Answer (score 1):

You may register at [Canonical](http://forms.canonical.com/capetown) to find when it is available. It is not available now but other Exynos Dual Core CPU devices (Samsung Chromebook) [do have it](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_nexus_7&num=1), so it is possible.